# Повернуть отдельный спрайт Android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, я делаю игру в качестве опыта и у меня возникла потребность максимально оптимально произвести поворот спрайта. Я знаю как нарисовать отдельный спрайт: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRect, paint)`, где `srcRect` — это часть изображения на экране, `destRect` — это та область экрана где будет произведена печать спрайта, а поворот я знаю что можно осуществить с помощью `matrix` (`canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint)`) используя свойство `translate`, то куда нужно производить печать и `rotate` — собственно сам поворот.

Так вот, мне необходимо повернуть отдельный спрайт и соответственно вывести его, но сделать это максимально оптимально, я предполагаю что можно создавать битмапу задавая эти параметры, но будет ли это быстро и оптимально по памяти, я думаю нет, есть ли решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавать новый битмап при каждой отрисовке спрайта - однозначно не хорошо.
Если нужен динамичный поворот на произвольный угол, то лучше использовать матрицу:

```
    // сохраняем настройки канваса
    canvas.save();
    // задаём его матрице поворот по центру нужной области
    // degress - угол в градусах
    canvas.rotate(degress,  destRect.exactCenterX(), destRect.exactCenterY());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRect, paint);
    // восстанавливаем настройки
    canvas.restore();
```

Если состояний у объекта по пальцам пересчитать, то возможно лучше заготовить спрайт на все состояния.
Тут палка о двух концах - либо больше вычислений, либо больше расход памяти.
Что для Вашего случая критичнее, то и оптимизируйте.

Comment: при минимальном кол-ве спрайтов всего может быть семь(или 15 от разного уровня графики), но отрисовка в таком случае 3-мя картинками  (если использовать только спрайты то их кол-во может перевалить за 100 штук), что посоветуешь лучше в таком случае использовать (3 картикни или больше кол-во битмап) мне больше нужно оптимизировать по производительности, но память забрасывать тоже не очень хочется?

Comment: И мне нужно поворачивать не сам canvas, а отдельный bitmap на нём